# Undefined Reference Error

Tags: c++, qt, g++

I am trying to use header and source files that are not part of the c++ library in the Qt Creator.

The header files I am trying to utilize are in a library called StanfordCPPLibrary.

Every time I try to use a function from the I get an undefined reference error. 
After researching online; I tried to add the correct SOURCES, LIBS to the .pro file -- I received different errors each time (I can post them here if required).

From my understanding so far; it is a linker error. I would highly appreciate if someone could point out what the error is and why is it caused so that I can learn as well. :)

Hi,

I am trying to use header and source files that are not part of the c++ library in the Qt Creator.

The header files I am trying to utilize are in a library called StanfordCPPLibrary.

The gwindow.h file is a part of the StanfordCPPLibrary.

Every time I try to use a function from the I get an undefined reference error.

From my understanding so far; it is a linker error. I would highly appreciate if someone could point out what the error is and why is it caused so that I can learn as well. :)

```
/*
* File: Rainbow.cpp
* --------------------------------------
* This program creates a rainbow that occupies a percentage of the screen chosen by the      end user
*/


#include <iostream>
#include "gwindow.h"



/*Function Prototype*/
void drawRainbow(GWindow & gw);

int main ()
{
GWindow gw;
drawRainbow(gw);
return 0;
}

void drawRainbow(GWindow & gw)
{
gw.drawRect(2, 2, 5, 5);
}
```

Here is the Project file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp
INCLUDEPATH = C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\Tools\mingw48_32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-  mingw32\4.8.0\include\StanfordCPPLib\
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using a library add the following to your pro file:

```
LIBS += -LPath\TO\LIB -lnameOfLib
```

This will tell the linker what to link and where to find the library. In the name of the library omit the extension.

For using sources you will need to copy the sources (.cpp .h) to your project folder or subfolder (or add their location to the sources path) and include them in SOURCES and HEADERS or add them as a subproject, creating object files which then will be linked. If using subproject include the subprojects .pri file in your original .pro file. There is a block about "Subdir Projects" at http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator/creator-project-creating.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried your suggestion and one more after some looking around.                                                    LIBS += -L"C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\Tools\mingw48_32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.0\include\StanfordCPPLib\gwindow " -lgwindow ----- I am now getting the error: cannot find -lgwindow. The .cpp file and .h file for gwindow exists in the above directory. Why is the error still happening? THanks!

Comment: Is this a shared or a static library? Shared libraries need the .dll and a .lib(for linking) on windows. Is the library really located in a directory called gwindow in StanfordCPPLib directory? The name of the library is gwindow.dll/gwindow.lib?

Comment: It is a .cpp for implentation and a .h for the interface; it is not a .dll or .lib . Here is the directory: include\StanfordCPPLib\gwindow.cpp         .... As you can see above I have already tried to use INCLUDEPATH but I am still getting an undefined reference error.

Comment: Sorry i misread your intention then. Try importing these files to your project (Add the files to SOURCES and HEADERS in pro file). Is the given cpp and h file eventually an example of the StranforcCPPLib?

Comment: I just did a quick lookup for the library. If you do have the sources from the libray, copy the needed files (.cpp .h) to your project folder and add them to your SOURCES and HEADERS section in pro-file. If you intend to use the library (not the source) setup INCLUDEPATH and LIBS as mentioned and just include the header file in your code.

Comment: I think I will have to dig deeper. I tried doing what you mentioned and am now getting the following error: :-1: error: No rule to make target 'gtypes.cpp', needed by 'debug/gtypes.o'.  Stop.   === could you point out the logic behind these steps. That will be very helpful.

Comment: So you did copy the cpp and h files to your directory and added them to SOURCES and HEADERS section? Did you run "qmake" after adding the files? If you simply copied the files to your folder and added both to SOURCES and HEADERS this should be enough to compile them into your project (after running qmake).

Comment: Yes, that is what I did. I saved the .pro and the .cpp file ; however I did not explicitly run qmake. Would you know what the meaning of this error is :  error: No rule to make target 'gtypes.cpp', needed by 'debug/gtypes.o'

Comment: Please look at my answer below : I could not fit all the info here.

Comment: Does it work now? As far as i can tell gwindow includes a lot more files, which may also have cpp files. Isn't it possible to create a static/shared lib from the stanfordcpplibrary sources? Then you could easily link to the library without worrying about all the massive includes.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my project folder with the gwindow.cpp file. So the only source file to be added is the gwindow.cpp file. I built the source again and received the same undefined reference errors -- 81 of them. Here is what the makefile.release is showing in the compile section.

```
####### Compile
release/main.o: ../Chap5/main.cpp ../Chap5/StanfordCPPLib/gwindow.h \
    ../Chap5/StanfordCPPLib/gtypes.h \
    ../Chap5/StanfordCPPLib/vector.h \
    ../Chap5/StanfordCPPLib/foreach.h \
    ../Chap5/StanfordCPPLib/strlib.h \
    ../Chap5/StanfordCPPLib/console.h \
    ../Chap5/StanfordCPPLib/private/main.h
$(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o release\main.o ..\Chap5\main.cpp

release/gwindow.o: ../Chap5/gwindow.cpp ../Chap5/StanfordCPPLib/gevents.h \
    ../Chap5/StanfordCPPLib/gtimer.h \
    ../Chap5/StanfordCPPLib/gwindow.h \
    ../Chap5/StanfordCPPLib/gtypes.h \
    ../Chap5/StanfordCPPLib/vector.h \
    ../Chap5/StanfordCPPLib/foreach.h \
    ../Chap5/StanfordCPPLib/strlib.h \
    ../Chap5/StanfordCPPLib/console.h \
    ../Chap5/StanfordCPPLib/private/main.h \
    ../Chap5/StanfordCPPLib/gobjects.h \
    ../Chap5/StanfordCPPLib/gmath.h \
    ../Chap5/StanfordCPPLib/map.h \
    ../Chap5/StanfordCPPLib/stack.h \
    ../Chap5/StanfordCPPLib/platform.h \
    ../Chap5/StanfordCPPLib/sound.h
$(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o release\gwindow.o ..\Chap5\gwindow.cpp
```